# Trying to decrypt a FormsAuthentication ticket always unable to validate data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership, asp.net-web-api

I am using the new webapi.

Now I don't know if I am doing this correctly but I am trying to setup my api to return an authentication cookie within the HttpResponseMessages header to use on another an mvc application.

I am using the FormsAuthenticationTicket as I think its what I need to use like

```
  public HttpResponseMessage Get(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (model.UserName == "bob")
        {
            //  if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            // {
            var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
            var auth = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, model.UserName, DateTime.Now, expires,
                                                     model.RememberMe,"password",
                                                     FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            var cookie = new HttpCookie("user");
            cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(auth);
            cookie.Domain = "localhost";
            cookie.Expires = expires;
            msg.Headers.Add("result",cookie.Value);
            return msg;
            //   }
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        //else
        //{
        //    return "The user name or password provided is incorrect.";
        //}
    }
```

now within my login controller on my mvc application I call the service and get the data value from the header I set in the api controller.

```
   string data = response.Headers["result"].ToString();
   FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(data);
```

Everytime I try running the FormsAuthentication.Decrypt I keep getting an error

> Unable to validate data.

I assume its due to when the api encrypts the data it uses some kind of key that the website doesn't know about. Am I right?

Can someone help out?

Thank you

Comment: What id the value of `data` in this line `string data = response.Headers["result"].ToString();` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I assume its due to when the api encrypts the data it uses some kind
>   of key that the website doesn't know about. Am I right?

FormsAuthentication.Encrypt and Decrypt methods use the [machine key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx). So make sure you have configured the same key for both your Web API web application and the consuming ASP.NET MVC application.

You could also take a look at the [following article](http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2011/10/11/oauth-2-0-in-web-api/) which illustrates how you could use OAuth 2.0 with the Web API.

Comment: Any idea how to throw an error such that I can clear my cookies and redirect the user to a controller from the exception? My cookies persist, hence I get stuck in a redirect loop. This occurs when I update my keys. Web API return 401 but MVC redirect to login page, and the login page request sends back the cookie again which throws the unauthorized response. Stuck in a vicious loop!